# How to display all the elements on the same point using ItemsControl wpf

Tags: wpf-controls

I want to disply all my elipse in the same point using itemControl wpf. by default itemsControl use vertical stackpanel. there's a way to simply remove the StackPanel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can give a custom [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) by either set one in your ItemsControl ControlTemplate, and using the IsItemsHost property to tell which of the panels is the receiver of the items.

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Canvas IsItemsHost="True"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

or by supplying a custom ItemsPanel and telling the position in the template by an ItemsPresenter.

```
<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ItemsPresenter/>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Canvas/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```